# PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column comments.post_id does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I cant seem to figure out why I keep getting this error. I am trying to add comment forms to a blog I am making and it wont work. Here is what the full error says.

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Posts#show

Showing /Users/ipbyrne/FirstRailsApp/blog/app/views/posts/show.html.erb where line #17 raised:

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column comments.post_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments"  WHERE "comments"."post_id" ...
                                               ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments"  WHERE "comments"."post_id" = $1

```
</p>

   <div id="comments">
       <h2><%= @post.comments.count %> Comments</h2> <-- Says it breaks here
       <%= render @post.comments %>

       <h3>Add a comment:</h3>
```

From what i can understand there is a column missing in one of the tables in the schema.rb file? Incase this the case here is what mine looks like

```
# encoding: UTF-8
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140911230918) do

  create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "comments", ["post_id"], name: "index_comments_on_post_id"

  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Comment: You need to create a new migration to add post_id column to the comments table, then migrate your database, then create a new comment.

Comment: is there a function I do that does this?

Comment: @Isaac were either of the answers helpful?

Comment: yes it did end being a problem with the migration. I apologize it took me so long to get back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're missing the field `post_id` on the `Comment` model, which would tell Rails which comments belong to which posts.

You can add it by generating a migration from the command line like so:

```
rails generate migration AddPostIdToComments post:references
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: How i created the comment it uses the post as reference so when the comment model is created it makes it belong to the post

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying -- are you asking how to create a comment with a reference to a post? or are you saying you've done this already?

Comment: @user1852651 That's inaccurate; `post:references` and `post:belongs_to` are effectively synonymous in this case. AFAIK there's no built-in generator for polymorphic associations.

Comment: @eirikir Check this out: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: @user1852651 The linked article makes no mention of generators

Comment: To generate a polymorphic association in the terminal, you use `rails g migration add_postable_type_to_comments postable:references`. That's an example. That would create **two** columns in the comments table: `postable_id` and `postable_type`. The `postable_type` column stores the class name of what the comment belongs to. So if we had pictures and posts and both could have comments, then then it would fill that column with the word `Picture` or `Post` respectively for each entry.

Comment: @user1852651 That's inaccurate. They generate the same code. I'm not sure how else to explain it to you.

Comment: @user1852651 The Rails guide on migrations makes clear that `belongs_to` is an alias for `references` for migration generators: "the generator accepts column type as references(also available as belongs_to)"(http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration)

Answer (score 5):

You probably just need to add the column into your `comments` table.

You can do that by creating a migration via the terminal to add the column in:

```
$ rails g migration add_post_id_column_to_comments post:belongs_to
$ rake db:migrate
```

The reason you want to use `post:belongs_to` is that Rails will automatically append the `_id` suffix and create a foreign key in the comments table to refer back to each other.

So essentially this part of the migration `post:belongs_to` will add the column `post_id` to your comments table. (Same thing if you did for example `cars:belongs_to`, you would get `cars_id`, etc)

That way you can be able to refer to the post's comments like this:

```
@post.comments
```

The reason why your `@post.comments` is failing now is that it is looking for that `post_id` column that you have not made yet which is probably also because you may not have defined the relationship between your `Post` and `Comment` models.

---

If you haven't done so already you just need to quickly define the relationship in each model:

- A post *has many* comments.
- A comment `belongs to` a post.

Get the lingo?

In your `Post` model, just add

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments   # make sure it's pluralized
end
```

and in your `Comment` model, add

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post  # and this one is singularized
end
```

Then try running your app again. Let me know how it goes.